# Correct param type for piping from Get-Content (PowerShell)?

Tags: powershell, pipe

What is the correct type for piping all of the content from Get-Content?

*My script:*

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [???]$content
)

Write-Output $content
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1#description) for PowerShell 5.1, Get-Content returns "a collection of objects", but  I'm not sure how to specify that in PowerShell. Without specifying a type for the `[???]`, only the last line of the file is output.

Comment: `[string[]]` or `[string]` depending on if you want to take pipeline input only or have it working with positional binding or named parameter. but you're missing a `process` block in your script

Comment: When I specify `[string]` or `[string[]]`, it is still only printing out the last line of the file. Is this related to missing the `process` block?

Comment: It's really `[object[]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last comment:

> When I specify `[string]` or `[string[]]`, it is still only printing out the last line of the file. Is this related to missing the process block?

This is correct, otherwise your **function, scriptblock or script** is executed in the [`end` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#end), if you want them to be able to process input from pipeline, you must add your logic in the [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process).

**Note**, this assumes you want to use [`ValueFromPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipeline-argument) which, in effect, converts it into an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2).

If you want it be able to process input from pipeline but also be compatible with [positional binding and named parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2) you would use `[string[]]` and a loop:

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]] $Content
)

process {
    foreach($line in $Content) {
        $line
    }
}
```

Then, assuming the above is called `myScript.ps1`, you would be able to:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | .\myScript.ps1
```

And also:

```
.\myScript.ps1 (Get-Content .\test.txt)
```